# update one row only in oracle sqldevelop

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am newbie in oracle sqldevelop.
i have trouble in update table like this.

```
table1
+----+-----------+------------+
| id |  acoount  |    date    |
+----+-----------+------------+
|    |  John     |  2/6/2016  | 
|    |  John     |  2/6/2016  |
```

i have table with name table1. i want to update id where the update only one rows.
Example :

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id |  acoount  |    date    |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 |  John     |  2/6/2016  | 
|  2 |  John     |  2/6/2016  |
```

how the solution. Thanks

Comment: Careful when tagging. sql server <> oracle.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's very unclear what you are asking. Do you want to update only one row of table1 when both account and date are the same? I assume the table doesn't have any primary key?

Comment: yes, no primary key, actually the id wil become pk

Comment: Hi Henz,  -  your answer made things less clear, not more. If you have several rows, with a few account's and date's (but also with duplicates), do you want the id's to be different across **the entire table**? That's what primary key means. Or do you want different id's only for duplicate rows - and perhaps for rows that are not duplicate, they should all have 1 in the id column? The two possible meanings of your question couldn't be more different from each other!

Comment: There is an answer in another thread.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085377/update-entire-table-with-sequence-number-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( id,  account, "date" ) AS
SELECT CAST( NULL AS INT ), 'John', DATE '2016-06-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT CAST( NULL AS INT ), 'John', DATE '2016-06-02' FROM DUAL;
```

**Update**:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 d
USING ( SELECT ROWNUM AS id, ROWID AS rid FROM Table1 ) s
      ON ( d.ROWID = s.RID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET d.id = s.id;
```

**Result**:

```
SELECT * FROM table1;

        ID ACCOUNT date              
---------- ------- -------------------
         1 John    2016-06-02 00:00:00 
         2 John    2016-06-02 00:00:00
```